# The affine scheme Spec $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a curve over F1 too?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

I read that we can considerate the affine scheme $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ like a curve over $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_1)$ where $\mathbb{F}_1$ is the field with one element.

So, can we also considerate $\mathcal{O}_K$ (ring of integers of a number field $K$) as a curve over $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_1)$ too ?

Comment: This is just "phylosophically" true, because as you know there is no field with one element. It's a way to think about the similarity between $\operatorname{Spec}(\Bbb Z)$ and $\operatorname{Spec}(k[X])$.

Comment: Sure, since every scheme is a scheme over $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ and $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ is a scheme over $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_1)$ (in whatever model of $\mathbb{F}_1$-geometry you take), you of course get a structure map by composition.

Comment: Thank you for your answers !